# How to return a object method in a jquery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I am trying to return an object method on the event `jQuery.change()` of a text field,
here is the code:

```
var Utente = function(indice){

    this.Indice = indice;
    this.Dati = new Array();

    this.initialize = function() {
        this.Dati['stato_civile'] = this.getField('stato_civile').val();
        this.onChange('stato_civile',this.checkObbligatorieta);
    }

    this.getField = function(name) {
        return $('#'+indice+name);
    }

    this.onChange = function(field, func) {

        this.getField(field).live('change',function() {
            return func.apply(); 
        });

    }

    this.checkObbligatorieta = function() {

         this.Dati['stato_civile'] = this.getField('stato_civile').val();

         [...]

    }

    this.initialize();

}
```

Using this I get the field `"#stato_civile"` returns the function `this.checkObbligatorieta` correctly but it gives me an error:
** `this.getField('stato_civile').val()` is not a function

I think it's something strictly related with the scope, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're not invoking `func()` in the same context as the caller, so `this` is not bound to the same object.

You can fix the problem by passing `this` to [apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
this.onChange = function(field, func) {
    this.getField(field).live("change", function() {
        return func.apply(this);
    });
};
```